# Google Photos Oauth2 flow returns error 502

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, google-photos-api

I am attempting to use the Google Photos API via my django based web application. 
During the Oauth flow I am getting error 502 bad gateway.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was barking up the wrong tree the whole time. However due to the lack of feedback when you google the above title I thought it best to give someone the heads up they need to solve this.

I was using code that is meant for an 'installed application'. This means when the I was attempting to redirect the user to Google to get authorisation the code was creating a local server to handle the 'flow'. This is clearly not going to work when running it from a deployed web application.

The solution and best guide I have found is [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). Hope this helps someone.